# Feth Jira Details in excel using python

Tags: python, json, jira, jira-rest-api

Using Python, I want to fetch Jira details, based on some Projects and assignees, to export to Excel.

```
import jira.client
from jira.client import JIRA

options = {'server': 'example.com', 'verify':False}
jira = JIRA(options, basic_auth=('user', 'pasword'))
issue=jira.issue('DWO-23981')
print(issue.fields.description)
```

Could you please provide suggestions on how to achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: What kinds of problems are you facing? Are you unable to fetch the data from Jira? Are you having trouble parsing the text? Are you unable to authenticate with the server? Be more descriptive.

Comment: @PrestonM No issue till now but want to know How to get details from jira in excel

Answer (score 0):

I am getting number of tickets here from this.

JIRA Issue: key=u'DWO-23931', id=u'2216443', JIRA Issue: key=u'DWO-23930', id=u'2216442',

I want these tickets in xlsx with all columns(Key,Summary,Status,Tag etc) like we do export all column from Jira in CSV format.

I hope you guys getting me.

Thanks,